# Use of the verb покидать

Tags: узус

In the following sentence, is this the same as saying the parents "couldn't shake" their feeling of concern?

С са́мого нача́ла роди́телей **не покида́ла** трево́га.

Comment: **Покидать** means simply 'to leave, to abandon', so 'the feeling of concern didn't leave the parents.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не покида́ла means here `didn't leave` so the entire sentence translation is something like `From the very beginning the feeling of concern didn't leave the parents`.